# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number for type date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am retrieving the date and time from the database table and converting to string using the server side (ruby on rails)
When I pass the date and time in the script variable I get the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number` error.
   This is my code,for the last line I get the error

```
 <% @adminstart.each do |name| %>
<% time = name.strtime %>
<% date = name.date %>
<% end %>
<% t1_s = time.strftime("%H:%M")%>
<% datetime = date.to_s+" "+t1_s %> 
var date = new Date(<%= datetime %>);
```

In the console I can see this

```
var date = new Date(2014-04-11 11:30);
```

The date and time is correct,but i dont know why it isnt getting parsed as a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The date and time is correct,but i dont know why it isnt getting parsed as a date

Because it's not a string. You're sending JavaScript code with syntax errors to the browser. The minimal change is to put it in quotes:

```
var date = new Date("<%= datetime %>");
```

so the browser sees

```
var date = new Date("2014-04-11 11:30");
```

which it at least has a chance of parsing. Note, though, that some older browsers may not parse that correctly. If you can, use the version of the `Date` constructor that accepts a number (milliseconds since The Epoch [midnight January 1st 1970 UTC]) rather than a string, to avoid parsing the string.

I'm not a Ruby person, but this answer suggests you can get seconds since The Epoch via `datetime.to_time.to_i`, so we multiply that by a thousand to get milliseconds:

```
var date = new Date(<%= datetime.to_time_to_i * 1000 %>);
```